# How to rename by a sequence in seq/nl/...?

Tags: shell-script, awk, rename

Assume you have a list of files with random base names, some of of them have a order such as the following input example. 
I really would like to do this by `nl`/`seq`/..., not by some loop approaches as proposed in the thread [Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers).
If no series found in basenames, then alphabetical order

```
1.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, 7.jpg, blooremaa.jpg, bloraem.jpg
```

Expected output

```
1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg, blooraem.jpg, blooremaa.jpg
```

Pseudocode

- just get a list of files
- rename them by an increasing series

Pseudocode attempt where the last part makes a change in the filenames of the list of files

```
# http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332413/16920
ls *.jpg | ... TODO ...                      \
  | sed 's/ *\([0-9]\+\)\.\(.*\)/\2 \1\.\2/' \ 
  | xargs -n 2 mv
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: “the last item in the splitted list” → see basename(1)

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211595/renaming-files-in-a-folder-to-sequential-numbers

Comment: @IporSircer I kind of disagree with the accepted answer of your proposed thread. Absolutely too wide open windows.

Comment: Is there a question in here? Superficially at least, it seems your question is actually an answer in need of its own question.

Comment: @roaima The pseudocode is an attempt but I am not happy about it. Something more robust must exist.