# How to prepend numerical order on filenames by Zsh/AWK/...?

Tags: awk, zsh, rename, nl

I would like to prepend numerical order form 1-777 on the orders given to it. 
You can loop it through and increment variable in Bash. 
However, I would like to do it with Zsh and/or Awk. 
An example follows. 
Filenames

```
IMG_20161215_081850.jpg
IMG_20161215_081851.jpg
IMG_20161215_090559.jpg
IMG_20161215_090601.jpg
IMG_20161215_091308.jpg
```

Wanted

```
1.IMG_20161215_081850.jpg
2.IMG_20161215_081851.jpg
3.IMG_20161215_090559.jpg
4.IMG_20161215_090601.jpg
5.IMG_20161215_091308.jpg
```

OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Is this a "visual" thing only (having the current number displayed when listing the files) or do you want to rename the files ?

Comment: @don_crissti I want to rename the files.

Comment: There's plenty of similar questions if you search [tag:rename] e.g. [1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26474), [2](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/281794) so in your case `autoload zmv` then `i=0; zmv -n '*' '$((++i)).$f'` and remove the `-n` if you like what you see...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ls *.jpg | nl -s.
```

`nl` will add line numbers; `-s.` specifies a `.` as the separator between the number and the data (in this case, the file names).  If you want to remove the leading spaces from the output, you can add this:

```
ls *.jpg | nl -s. | sed 's/^ *//'
```

`sed` will then remove zero or more spaces from the start of the line.

If you really want to do this with `awk`:

```
ls *.jpg | awk '{ print NR"."$0 }'
```

`NR` is an internal variable indicating the number of records thus far parsed.

To make permanent changes in filenames, do the following (Michael Vehrs)

```
ls *.jpg | nl -s. | sed 's/ *\([0-9]\+\)\.\(.*\)/\2 \1\.\2/' | xargs -n 2 mv
```

Comment: How can you make the changes permanent in filenames? - - I think your `nl` approach is outstanding. I actually did not know about the command.

Comment: You need to pipe the result to `mv`, like this `ls *.jpg | nl -s. | sed 's/ *\([0-9]\+\)\.\(.*\)/\2 \1\.\2/' | xargs -n 2 mv`.

Answer (score 4):

With zsh, use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) to perform bulk renaming. First run `autoload -U zmv` (put this in your `.zshrc`), then

```
i=1
zmv 'IMG_*.jpg' '$((i++)).$f'
```

Comment: Confirmed. This works as expected in Debian 8.5.